# Nativescript camera

Tags: camera, nativescript

After `import * as camera from "nativescript-camera";` I got this error upon: ns debug android

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-camera/camera.android.js 21:24-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/utils/utils'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

1. Go to  `node_modules/tns-core-modules/utils.d.ts`
2. Update the `utils.d.ts` with following: `export * from "@nativescript/core/utils/utils";`
3. `npm install`
4. Run application

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the package `@nativescript-camera`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).